# why is this.setState not updating my state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a lot of code for this to do list in 3 different files, so I'm just going to give you what I think is critical to understanding this problem.

I have my state

```
state = { items: [], currentItem: {text:'', key:'', checked: false, textStrike: null}};
```

And when I try to setState in a function the console.log doesn't display the updated info.

```
completeItem = (item) => {
   let itemsArr = [...this.state.items];
   itemsArr.forEach((oneItem) => {
      if(item.key === oneItem.key) {
         this.setState({ checked: true, textStrike: 'strike'}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.items)
         })
      }
   });
};
```

The console.log displays the old info and never updates.

Comment: Are you saying that `this.state.items` is giving the old one? But you are not changing `items` state at all.

Comment: console.log(item.key === oneItem.key) returns what?

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant doing this?

As per your question (initial state) I guess you should be using

```
this.setState({ currentItem: { checked: true, textStrike: 'strike' } })
```

In your example, you are not updating this.state.currentItem, rather you are just updating this.state
Which means, your new state would be an object with structure:

```
{
 "items":[], 
 "checked":true,
 "textStrike":"strike" 
}
```

Also, you are verifying this.state.items which will not be updated rather you should do a `console.log(this.state.currentItem)` or  `console.log(this.state)` to verify this

Answer (score 0):

Add the return statement to the function inside your setState

Answer (score 0):

First, in *console.log* you're typing **this.state.items**, but you don't set **items** in your setState(), and therefore items don't change. I believe that's why you don't see any changes.

Second, in setState() you're setting the following object:

```
{
     checked: true, 
     textStrike: 'strike'
}
```

But according to your state structure, it should be wrapped into currentItem:

```
this.setState({
     currentItem: {
          checked: true, 
          textStrike: 'strike'
     }
})
```

And finally, my advice to you is not to call setState() inside loop. I recommend you to prepare new state first, and then call setState() once.

Comment: I agree your point not to do setState() in loop. We can just make a new object and once the entire loop is done, just update state once.